# Android ImageView control show its own generate image

Tags: android

I want to display an image in ImageView control. This image codes the EditText information into two-dimension code in same Activity.

So how should I realize this by code?

Comment: Please specify what do you mean by "codes the EditText information into two-dimension code". Is it QR code which is meant or something else?

Answer (score 1):

```
mageView iv = new ImageView(this);
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.ButtonRecalculate);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
rl.addView(iv, lp);
```

Comment: I think he wants to set image via code, on something hes generated. Not via xml. You have declared the IMageView but do nothing with it..

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own `Drawable` class and set an instance of that class as your `ImageView`s image.